# Why wont Netbeans upload correctly to my php sever

Tags: windows, netbeans, ftp

I am using Netbeans to work on my php server. When I try to upload my project, there are no errors, but the files remain unchanged on the server.

Example: I change height from 10% to 7% in css and upload. No errors occur, but height remains unchanged on the site.

Log (Octothorpes used to remove sensitive info):

> 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5 Server (Debian) [::ffff:###.###.#.##]
>
> USER ########
>
> 331 Password required for ########
>
> PASS ******
>
> 230 User ######## logged in
>
> TYPE I
>
> 200 Type set to I
>
> CWD /var/www/html/www.example.com
>
> 250 CWD command successful
>
> PWD
>
> 257 "/var/www/html/www.example.com" is the current directory
>
> CWD /var/www/html/www.example.com/styles/css
>
> 250 CWD command successful
>
> CWD /var/www/html/www.example.com/styles/css
>
> 250 CWD command successful
>
> PASV
>
> 227 Entering Passive Mode (##,###,##,##,###,#).
>
> STOR main.css.new
>
> 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for main.css.new
>
> 226 Transfer complete
>
> RNFR main.css.new
>
> 350 File or directory exists, ready for destination name
>
> RNTO main.css
>
> 250 Rename successful
>
> CWD /var/www/html/www.example.com/styles
>
> 250 CWD command successful
>
> QUIT
>
> 221 Goodbye.
>
> Summary
>
> ====================
>
> Succeeded:
>
> dir       styles
>
> dir       styles/css
>
> file      styles/css/main.css
>
> Runtime: 19 ms, processed: 1 file(s), 1.34 KB

Extra info:

Client running windows 8.1 64 bit
Server running Ubuntu 64 bit
Server is on local network
FTP credentials are correct
Connection worked client-side previously on Windows 7 64 bit and Ubuntu 64 bit

Comment: Did you check to see if your browser cached the css file when you changed the height? in that case, you wouldn't see a change

Comment: I feel idiotic that I did not think of that. That was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer so others know the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't disable caching on your browser it will store old versions of files (css, js, jpg, etc) and you won't see your changes. Disable caching and it should work.